# automatic redirect after data validation

Tags: php

I have a question. Suppose i have 2 forms in 2 different .htm pages. I want to validate the 1st form first and sumbit the data in that form to a database using php. I do that. But then i want to automatically go to the next form if the data in the first form was validated and submitted to the database. How do I do that ? I am just a newbie in php and mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header("Location: http://localhost/form2.php");
exit();
```

If the second form lives in form2.php. (Just change the url to what you want to redirect to).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this :-

```
window.location.href = 'http://url';
```

Answer (score 0):

As a 3rd option you could do a meta redirection although this could damage your SEO, people think...

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=path/to/secondscript.php" />
```